# Service said installed but not showing up in services list in task manager?

Tags: c#, service

I am trying to run service that i created in .net its for sending out emails at specific times. I added the installer to the service and installed it via the following to commands

> cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
>
> InstallUtil.exe C:\Projects\apertureNetService\apertureNetService\bin\Debug\apertureNetService.exe

How ever when it completed it said that it had compelted ok but still no sign of it in my services list ?.

http://snag.gy/7a215.jpg

Service list no error is showing as you can see from the screengrab sorry I do not know how to add an image when i below ten points.

http://snag.gy/pQujh.jpg

Comment: click "Open Services" and see if you see your service there?

Comment: @ClearLogic Yes I do its their but showing as stoped when i try to start it with net start is says invalid Service name Service1 yet the asebmly as you see their is call ApertureNetServices

Comment: what happens when you try to start from GUI

Comment: @ClearLogic it says the service did not respond to start or control request  in a temiley function

Comment: You need to attach debugger to properly debug this.Do you know how to do that?